# Vite and laravel multi bundling

Tags: laravel, gulp, vite

I'm using Laravel 9.19 which ships with Vite, I want to build a separated js files for each page in my website by bundling multiple js files into 1 file
for example:

```
 script_homepage: {
        src: [
            'resources/js/lib/jquery.min.js',
            'resources/js/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
            'resources/js/lib/blazy.min.js',
            'resources/js/lib/swiper.min.js',
            'resources/js/lib/fontawesome.min.js',
            'resources/js/lib/wow-animate.min.js',
            'resources/js/common.js',
            'resources/js/homepage.js',
        ],
        dest: 'public/js'
    }

script_shop: {
    src: [
        'resources/js/lib/jquery.min.js',
        'resources/js/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        'resources/js/lib/blazy.min.js',
        'resources/js/lib/fontawesome.min.js',
        'resources/js/lib/wow-animate.min.js',
        'resources/js/common.js',
        'resources/js/parts/accordion.js',
        'resources/js/shop.js',
    ],
    dest: 'public/js'
},
```

I used to use gulp to achieve the above and I want to use Vite if its possible

Comment: I wish to do the same. Do you found a solution?

Comment: Same...any luck on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin [vite-multi-bundler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-multi-bundler)

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import viteMultiBundler from "vite-multi-bundler";

export default defineConfig({
  // Note: While giving the file name, you don't need to add the file extension. The plugin handles this automatically on its own.

  plugins: [
    viteMultiBundler({
      file_versioning: true, // default => true
      js: [
        {
          filename: "backend", // after bundling, => backend-[file_version].js
          entryPoints: ["src/admin.js", "src/user.js"],
        },
        {
          filename: "bundled.min", // after bundling, => bundled.min-[file_version].js
          entryPoints: ["test/roles.js"],
        },
      ],
      css: [
        {
          filename: "common", // after bundling, => common-[file_version].css
          entryPoints: ["src/user.css", "src/admin.css"],
        },
        {
          filename: "bundled.min", // after bundling, => bundled.min-[file_version].css
          entryPoints: ["test/elements.css"],
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

You can specify as many files as you want in entrypoints and it generates the the bundled file inside `/dist` or any directory that you specify in `build.outDir`

Comment: Hi Waleed, this looks like it might do what I want to do. How would I use this with Laravel? I would need to make it work with the laravel-vite-plugin, I believe. Also, I only need this for the build script. Is that how it works?

Comment: Anyone configured this for laravel?